# Gain of photodetectors

Tags: gain, photodiode, detector

[image]

I found this in a lecture about ["Optical Wireless Communications."](https://slideplayer.com/slide/1433164/) It is slide 15.

Does anyone have idea how gain was computed?

Comment: I's assume it is Avalanche Photo Diode (APD) sensitivity versus PIN (P-Intrinsic-N)  sensitivity as '1'  https://electronics360.globalspec.com/article/10397/pin-vs-apd-different-sensitivity-different-applications

Comment: @DaveX, responsivity, not sensitivity. But otherwise,, yes.

Comment: Seriously, the term is defined on slide 14, i.e. literally a slide before. -1.

Answer (score 4):

Gain in this case refers to photoelectron gain, which is the number of photoelectrons generated by each absorbed photon.  For a conventional photodiode, each absorbed photon releases one photoelectron, leading to a gain of exactly 1.0.

For an avalanche photodiode, that electron is accelerated through a large voltage, which liberates additional electrons.  Thus, the gain of an avalanche diode is much larger than one.  The exact gain will depend on the reverse bias voltage and the design of the specific diode, so the values given are only approximate and are not easy to calculate.  For specialized devices such single photon avalanche diodes, the gain can be orders of magnitude larger, although they devices lose the ability to detect multiple photons concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error tells me it is the Responsivity/Quantum Efficiency for each APD divided against the same ratio for the PIN which makes the PIN the reference (which is why the PIN is always 1).